# preferred method of performing background tasks in WPF MVVM command behaviors

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

i know this question is a bit subjective.. but i am basically looking to see if there is a better way of doing this than what i came up with.

i have a basic MVVM setup, where a treeview is bound to a tree structure.

this structure has nodes that load on demand.

when i expand a node, i fire off a command behavior, in this behavior, i query the necessary data, and add it to the node.

**my first instinct is to use a background worker (within command behavior event), to which i pass the id of the node i am expanding. upon completion, the worker will find that node, and append it's children.**

This is an approach i inherited from winforms development. Curious if there is a better architectural solution for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We currently use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) because it makes it easier to pass data to the method to execute and makes your code look more like a typical synchronous method which is usually easier to read and understand. It also gets you closer to the async and await style of coding which will be coming with .NET 4.5 and is really important for Windows 8 programming.

Answer (score 2):

Bill's answer with the async/await pattern is good. For 4.0, I prefer the Task object:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Action);
```

Although it depends on what you are doing. Sometimes I use `BackgroundWorker` for its progress support.

Comment: And for it's completion on the UI thread. If you use a task how do you get the result to update the UI?

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew(Action).ContinueWith(UpdateAction);

Comment: That only works if the update action is executed on the UI thread.

Comment: @Cameron - the UpdateAction's implementation calls Dispatcher.Invoke for any UI actions. What's the beef here?

Comment: Just that Background Worker abstracts that thread marshalling away, and using tasks reintroduces it. I'm simply pointing out that when using tasks you have to be aware of this.